# Return Expression Check Condition in C++

Tags: c++, expression

Still getting used to the formatting when writing C++ code, come from a Lua background.
How do I correctly format a if/conditional expressions as my example highlights below.

This will correctly run, but with warnings which is unideal:

```
return (boolean == true) and init() or 0;
```

Highlighted Warning:

```
expected a ';'C/C++ (between "(boolean == true)" "and")
```

Comment: `and` and `or` are so rarely used, I would not be surprised if you are using some unusual C++ compiler that simply doesn't implement them. I'm curious which C++ textbook you're using, that features them? `boolean && init()` is the natural C++ syntax that should be logically equivalent to this exotic syntax.

Comment: Thanks @Sam Varshavchik, I didn't even stop to consider there may be duel support for both operator expressions. Strange that there's support at all (if there's any story there I'd love to hear). Happy to accept this as an answer if you want to post as a solution :)

Comment: Please don't tag C when asking about C++. They are not the same language or one a strict subset of the other. For example `and` and `or` behave differently between the two languages.

Comment: `and` and `or` need to be supported by every standard-conform C++ compiler. How are you trying to compile this? What compiler are you using? Anything from the last 20 years or more should be fine at the very least. Or is the warning just from the IDE? Did you maybe not set it up correctly to interpret the code as C++ (instead of C)? What IDE are you using, what file extension are you using?

Comment: Well, @user17732522, we still get occasional questions from lost souls who insist on using Turbo C++, for some reason...

Comment: BTW, there is absolutely no point in the trailing `or 0` ... when would that ever be significant?

Comment: Thanks for noticing @user17732522, looks like that's been sorted out now (C tag).

Comment: @user17732522 Just an in-editor IDE warning, the compiler ran without issue or warning, was confused over this discrepancy but that's kindly been addressed by @ sam-varshavchik. Everything was standard, `.cpp` file, Microsofts built in C++ Intellisense plugin and the popular Jeff Hykin's "Better C++ Syntax"

Comment: @Theo Ah I forgot that MSVC is weird like that. It is not very standard conforming at all if you are compiling in a pre-C++20 mode without the strict standards conformance option enabled (`/permissive-`). In the default pre-C++20 mode it doesn't support the `and` and `or` keyword directly. I would recommend enabling strict conformance mode anyway, not only because of this specific divergence from the standard.

Comment: @AdrianMole The `or 0` looks to me like unneeded baggage brought in from other-language knowledge. As I recall -- it has been a while since I've used Lua -- Lua is one of the languages where `or 0` is habitually used to ensure a value is `false` instead of `undefined` (where `undefined` is not a thing in C++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`and` and `or` are keywords are considered a bit archaic. They are technically valid C++ keywords in modern C++ (since C++98 it seems). You must be using a very old C++ compiler that was written before they were added to C++. They, and their usage, never took off. Classical `&&` and `||` operators continue to rule the roost and are not going anywhere.

Therefore: although it is true that this expression should be logically equivalent to `boolean && init()`, you might want to consider assigning somewhat higher priority of updating your C++ compiler to something more modern, if that's indeed the reason for the compilation error.

Comment: The problem here turns out to be MSVC (see question comments) which doesn't support the keywords if not set to strict conformance mode.